# What are the differences between A1 and A1/1?

Tags: english-to-german, book

I'm preparing for A1 German exam and found some books refer to A1/1:

- Menschen: Arbeitsbuch A1 MIT Audio-Cds
- MENSCHEN A1.1 Kursb
- Menschen A1 Kursbuch

What the difference between A1 and A1/1?

Comment: I vote to close this question because it has nothing to do with the German language per se.

Answer (score 2):

The A1 program is sometimes split into 3 parts: A1.1, A1.2, A1.3.

So this is just a way for MENSCHEN to divide their program into 3 smaller, more gullible parts.